# I want to change my ionic start page

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am working on the project but when I close the terminal, the project returns to the default screen when I come back.

My project files are as follows,
[click for photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RUJOS.png)

I want to start templates/anasayfa.html every time the app is opened

But it always comes across
[click for photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epSG9.png)

Answer (score 1):

in `ionic2+` you have to place all html files in seperate folders under `pages` folder. If you see your project there are two folders like home and list under pages folder. to create a new page use this command

```
ionic g page anasayfa
```

it will create a folder with  four files (.html,.ts and .scss type files)

now to make it as root page, we need to change root page in app.component.ts file like this

```
rootPage:any = anasayfaPage;
```